# Easeljs Tweenlite rotate around center

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs, gsap

I'm trying to get a `shape` object to rotate around its centre using `TweenLite` but it rotates around its `x` & `y`. Seems like the `transformOrigin` of `TweenLite` is not working. I am still new with `EaselJS` and `TweenLite`.

Please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phuongle2611/n0kyvh1j/2/) or take a look at the snippet below:

***Snippet:***

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

var shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.beginFill('#000');
shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 220, 220);
shape.graphics.endFill();
shape.x = 220;
shape.y = 220;
stage.addChild(shape);
stage.update();
//TweenLite.ticker.setFPS(40);
TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener('tick', stage.update, stage);

TweenLite.to(shape, 1, {
    repeat: -1,
    rotation: 360,
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%'
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EaselJS/0.8.0/easeljs.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `regX`and `regY` to transform something around its center, check the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n0kyvh1j/3/